# How do you prove $x \log x = a$ has a unique solution where $a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How would you go about proving this? From the graph of $y = x\log x$ it is clear the function is injective for $a > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show the following two facts:

1. $f(x)=x\log x$ takes all the non-negative values, when $x \ge 1$.
2. $f'(x)=\log x+1>0$, when $x>1$.

Fact 2. is clear. For 1., observe that $f(1)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, and thus, due to Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ takes all non-negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x \log x$ is continuous, right? Then there are three things you need to answer. What is the derivative of $x \log x$? Can $x \log x$ be negative? What is $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \log x$?

Comment: And $x \log x$ is continuous.

Comment: I was taking that as known, but good point that should be mentioned.